# Adding padding query insert to Listbox

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have read a number of threads and other resources to try to find the correct way to handle this but I have not found anything that works with my application.
Here is what I am trying to accomplish.

When a query is completed and the insert of the data to a Listbox is done I cannot seem to get it to margin the data insert by 1 character space.

I am using pack() and I have read the tkinter manual for this and have tried each example available along with others found on various threads here.

The widget:

```
output = tkinter.Listbox(window_2, height = 20, font='Times 10',
width=42, bd=1, bg = '#FFD599', fg = '#9A0615', selectmode=SINGLE)

output.pack()
output.place(x=210, y=195)
```

I have tried padx and pady with pack() without success, although this works successfully with the Text widget.  I have also attempted to use a few alternatives that I have found here on the site but all without success in margining the Listbox when the data is inserted.

Any advice?

Comment: Are you asking about padding _inside_ the lisbox or _outside_ the listbox? Please provide a [mcve]. `padx` should work just fine outside the listbox when using `pack`.

Comment: the padding is inside the Listbox, when the queried data is inserted into the Listbox it is directly against the border and I am attempting to margin the inserted data by 1 character space. When I use padx and pady.     
    instructions = tkinter.Text(window_2, font=('Times 10'), height = 21,
        width=42, bd=1, bg = '#FFD599', fg = '#9A0615',padx=5, pady=5)    

This works in the Text widget but not in Listbox

Answer (score 5):

`pack`'s `padx/pady` and `ipadx/ipady` options don't affect the data that is inside the listbox.  The listbox itself doesn't have any options to add an internal margin.

To get a margin around the inside of the listbox, what I normally do is give it a zero `borderwidth` and `highlightthickness`, and then place it in a frame with the same background color and let the frame be the border. You can then add any padding you want between the border and the listbox.

This is also convenient because you can put a scrollbar inside the frame, giving it the appearance that it is inside the listbox without actually being inside the listbox.

Example:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.configure(background="gray")
listbox_border = tk.Frame(root, bd=1, relief="sunken", background="white")
listbox_border.pack(padx=10, pady=10, fill=None, expand=False)

listbox = tk.Listbox(listbox_border, width=20, height=10,
                     borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0,
                     background=listbox_border.cget("background"),
)
vsb = tk.Scrollbar(listbox_border, orient="vertical", command=listbox.yview)
listbox.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb)
vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
listbox.pack(padx=10, pady=10, fill="both", expand=True)

for i in range(100):
    listbox.insert("end", "Item #{}".format(i))

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Bryan I appreciate the example.  I have looked at it and run it and it works fine as it is but when I implement it into my code it will not display the widget for some reason. I have used your example exactly, modifying root to window_2 for my need but it will not display at all.  There is no error when running the code but it will not display.

Answer (score 2):

here is a variation on the much appreciated answer by Bryan Oakley.

- it uses ttk widgets instead of tk widgets
- the scrollbar tracks your position in the list box when you scroll with the mouse
- uses the oStyle.theme_use("clam") because it may look more modern...this can be commented out

'

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

try:  # allows the text to be more crisp on a high dpi display
  from ctypes import windll
  windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(1)
except:
  pass

root = tk.Tk()
oStyle = ttk.Style()
oStyle.theme_use("clam")
oStyle.configure('LB.TFrame', bd=1, relief="sunken", background="white")
listbox_border = ttk.Frame(root, style='LB.TFrame')
listbox_border.pack(padx=4, pady=4, fill=None, expand=False)
vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(listbox_border)
vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
listbox = tk.Listbox(listbox_border, width=20, height=10, borderwidth=0,
                     highlightthickness=0, selectmode=tk.SINGLE,
                     activestyle=tk.NONE)
listbox.pack(padx=6, pady=6, fill="y", expand=True)
listbox.config(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
vsb.config(command=listbox.yview)
for i in range(100):
    listbox.insert("end", "Item #{}".format(i))

root.mainloop()
```

'
[image]

Answer (score 0):

first of all to format chars in a tkinter listbox you need to use a fixed font and .format python funcion....;

So you can do something this

Press Load to load data in the listbox and pay attention to this line code

**s = '{0:>8}{1:5}'.format(i[0],i[1])**

**self.list.insert(tk.END, s)**

```
import tkinter as tk

RS = (('Apple',10),
      ('Banana',20),
      ('Peack',8),
      ('Lemon',6),)

class App(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self,):

        super().__init__()

        self.master.title("Hello World")
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):

        self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1,)

        f = tk.Frame()

        sb = tk.Scrollbar(f,orient=tk.VERTICAL)

        self.list = tk.Listbox(f,
                    relief=tk.GROOVE,
                    selectmode=tk.BROWSE,
                    exportselection=0,
                    background = 'white',
                    font='TkFixedFont',
                    yscrollcommand=sb.set,)

        sb.config(command=self.list.yview)

        self.list.pack(side=tk.LEFT,fill=tk.BOTH, expand =1) 
        sb.pack(fill=tk.Y, expand=1)

        w = tk.Frame()

        tk.Button(w, text="Load", command=self.on_callback).pack()
        tk.Button(w, text="Close", command=self.on_close).pack()

        f.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=0)
        w.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=0)


    def on_callback(self,):

        for i in RS:
            s = '{0:>8}{1:5}'.format(i[0],i[1])
            self.list.insert(tk.END, s)


    def on_close(self):
        self.master.destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: ok so I have tried this but it does not work as it should and I am sure it my error when implementing the needed lines. 
`for recipe, in results:`

`s = '{0:>2}{1:5}'.format(recipe, recipe)`

`output.insert(END,s)`

Comment: This will insert the data from the query but it inserts it twice on the same line. I have played with the line to see if I could prevent that but without success. `s = '{0:>2}{1:5}'.format(recipe, recipe)` is clearly the imperative line for this to work but being reasonably new to python and tkinter I am not clear on what it performing in order to modify my code to work properly with this.